# Define image src tag using portion of an URL using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

With the code below, I am able to get a variable without a slash from the URL into my HTML.

```
    var pathArray = location.pathname.split( '-' );
    var URLwithoutDashes = pathArray[0];
    var URLwithoutSlash = URLwithoutDashes.substring(1);
    document.write(URLwithoutSlash);
```

Now I'd like to use it as my img src tag (with the extention .png), but I can't figure out how to do it. The code below doesn't seem to work.

```
    var pathArray = location.pathname.split( '-' );
    var URLwithoutDashes = pathArray[0];
    var URLwithoutSlash = URLwithoutDashes.substring(1);
    document.write("img src=\""URLwithoutSlash".png\">");
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: use alert("img src=\""URLwithoutSlash".png\">"); and see what it is alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
document.write("img src=\""URLwithoutSlash".png\">");
```

Should be:

```
document.write("<img src=\"" + URLwithoutSlash + ".png\">");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
document.write("<img src=\"" + URLwithoutSlash + ".png\" />");
```